# How do I point pip3 to my python3 folder? (Mac)

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, installation, pip

Right now if I do pip -V or pip3 -V they both point to the exact same place, which is inside of the Python 2.7 site-packages. How do I fix this so that pip3 points to inside of the python3 version?

Apparently I have two python3 installed? I have one inside of /usr/local and another one inside of usr/bin? Can someone help me to get pip3 working please.

[pip / pip3 - V](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCuVC.png)

[which -a python python3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOrru.png)

Comment: Can you use `python3 -m pip`?

Comment: I know Macs are very similar to Linux, but I don't know how much.  In BASH you could alias the pip3 command, so in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases` you'd add `function pip3() { Python3 -m pip $@ ;}`